# How can I include CSS files inside a media query in PUG template engine?

Tags: html, css, node.js, pug

Can I include `css` files inside a media query in my `index.pug` file? I have tried like this

```
style
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1170px)" href="../static/respnsive.css">
```

but nothing happened. Is there any other way of doing this and making a webpage responsive?

Answer (score 0):

```
meta(charset='UTF-8')
meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge')
meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
title CodeXpool
link(rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (max-device-width: 881px)' href='../static/style2.css')
```

Comment: Make sure that you have included meta tag also the css files inside head tag with proper indentation

Comment: add the above comment to your answer by editing it. thanks